# Handling different versions in TFS

Tags: tfs

I was wondering if someone could off advice with a problem i have in TFS.

I have a folder structure like so :-

```
- development
 - project gets branched to here for development
- drop
 - build drop folder
- main
 - project is in here
```

I have now been asked to create 2 versions. 1 for our production and 1 for our preproduction environment, so im wondering what's the best way to achieve this.

My thought is to change the structure like so :-

```
- development
 - project gets branched to here for development
- drop
 - Production
  - build drop folder
 - PreProduction
  - build drop folder for preproduction project
- main
 - Production
   - production project moved to here
 - PreProduction
   - preproduction project branched from production and placed in here
```

Comment: Having different versions of software for non-production versus production seems crazy. You're opening yourself up to undetected bugs in production. What's the business case for doing this?

Comment: Hopefully by "two different versions", the product owner really means "well, we only want some *features* enabled in production but we want others in pre-prod".  If that's the case, then only *one* version of the product should exist and feature flags should be used to enable / disable functionality.  As @DanielMann points out, having two separate code bases is madness.

Comment: Agree with the above comments, you should have only one version and I think your existing branching already supports it. You Dev branches are all the pre-prod versions. When they are ready to go to prod you merge to Main and deploy from there. Creating prod vs pre-prod main is signing up for trouble and defeating the purpose.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying guys.  Its only a temp measure to get round a specific problem on preprod that will get sorted in the near future, however thanks for answering the question i asked.  You've been a real help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is called "Release Branching".  I suggest this type of release branching primarily for large development teams only, as there is overhead associated with it.  Only do what is needed for your particular team.  I see this typically only when you have a development team, a release/operations team and a QA team.

The typical process I go through is a certification (several stages of pre-production deployments).  During the process of certification, bugs are found and fixed on a branch off of the release branch (release hotfix/dev line).  These hotfixes are typically not brought back into the main development line.

After Certification is complete and the code is ready for the production environment, it is branched one last time.  To help visualize, see image below.
[image: Release Branching]

Comment: It should be noted that each certification line is assocated with a major release, while locked releases are minor releases under that.

Comment: It should also be noted that building modern software in an agile fashion is mutually exclusive to the branching structure described above. Best to avoid branching if at all possible. Use feature toggles instead.